# Android Studio-Error:Execution failed for task ':app in

Tags: java, android

When I run my app I am getting these error is something pointing to graphics/drawable. I searched through various websites but none of that gave solution.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v4/graphics/drawable/DrawableCompat.class
```

Here is my build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.rajkumar.layout"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
        'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    configurations {
        all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-     
core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'gr.pantrif:easy-android-splash-screen:0.0.1'
compile 'com.felipecsl:gifimageview:2.1.0'
compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'
compile 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.1.17'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile files('libs/activation.jar')
compile files('libs/additionnal.jar')
compile files('libs/mail.jar')
}
```

Can Anyone help me how to solve this issue.
Thank You

Comment: I think you have two drawable of the same name in res >> drawable folder.

Comment: no am having one drawable folder.

Answer (score 0):

You have to exclude the module

compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'
compile ('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1') {
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
}
compile ('pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.1.17') {
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
}
compile ('com.felipecsl:gifimageview:2.1.0') {
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
}

Comment: since am new to android can you point out how to exclude in gradle file.please

Comment: in your build gargle you have to change the compile...I have already written for you..please check

Comment: exclude from all the compile you have and check